# Can't install SoundWireServer

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I am trying to install SoundWireServer on Ubuntu 32-bit.

I have already installed libportaudio

```
sudo apt-get install libportaudio2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libportaudio2 is already the newest version (19.6.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

but when try to run SoundWireServer. it gives the following:

```
./SoundWireServer: error while loading shared libraries: libportaudio.so.2:   
 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?